# Flutter app stuck on black screen when resuming on Android

Tags: flutter

am so so sorry if am duplicating an already-asked question, but following similar questions that have already been asked tend to be very different from what am actually facing.

I have these two apps, one is on the store (iOS Store and PlayStore), one is currently being develop,

I observe some issues with them, I noticed that Flutter flashes black screen on Android when resuming and this also happens to the app on the store as well

The black screen will persist except I removed it and open the app again

have followed this discussion on Github but could not resolve it, this discussion  in Github perfectly said what am facing but tried all the solution there but did not work form me
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59552

please how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does that black screen only appear for a few seconds (or milliseconds)?

Comment: No, it appear there till I remove the app from recent app and click on the icon again or I will navigate to other app and come back and click on the app again

Comment: am facing same issue, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Anyone with solution????

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by deleting the app and rerunning it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32894369)